# React-native CLI gradle BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

when i run my project i get build error like this. I started getting this error in my last project and my project is not opening. But there is no such error in my previous projects, they work without any problems while running them.

PS C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app> npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/Bilal/.gradle/caches/jars-9/ed982d2a7012eb31e78a8c4df346a1ad/react-native-gradle-plugin.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.facebook.react.properties.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find implementation class 'com.facebook.react.ReactPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/Bilal/.gradle/caches/jars-9/ed982d2a7012eb31e78a8c4df346a1ad/react-native-gradle-plugin.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.facebook.react.properties.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 3s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\menu\menu_app>

The things I did to fix it was to clean the gradle with the ./gradle clean command, but my command didn't work, it was working in my other projects. I tried to fix it by resetting the invalidate cache from Android studio, but it didn't work. Can you help with my problem? I am ready to provide other necessary information. What are your suggestions? If I reinstall from scratch, will it be android studio?

Comment: can you share your package.json file ?

i would suggest in your project root directory, first run :

 rm -rf node_modules

check your react-native version and rn-gradle version if they are compatible.

check compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle file in app if its defined then good otherwise define a SDK version.

and run npm install.
Let me know what do you get after following this.